# WPF: What Event Happen after downloaded a image

Tags: wpf, image, events

in my application, i am using following statement for display a image

```
 menuUserImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(UserImagePath, UriKind.Absolute));
```

here **UserImagePath** is the URL of image which is on the web.  This statement download a image and display a image. I want to display a circular progress bar until image is not displayed. So i want to ask that which event fire after image is downloaded so i can hide the progress bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could handle [BitmapSource.DownloadCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.downloadcompleted.aspx) Event here.

It allows you to hide your animation once the image is loaded.